# Explain useUserSearch hook for ReactJS that uses axios

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios

I'm trying to wrap my head around this code. It essentially sends two params (page number + query) to a server, then gets the results and saves them in a state.

However, I don't understand the cancel, axios.CancelToken...etc part within useEffect. I would appreciate if it someone explains this thoroughly.

```js
import axios from "axios";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function useUserSearch(query, pageNumber) {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const [hasMore, setHasMore] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    setError(false);
    let cancel;
    axios
      .get("https://someserver.com/users/search/", {
        params: { q: query, page: pageNumber },
        cancelToken: new axios.CancelToken((c) => (cancel = c)),
      })
      .then((res) => {
        setUsers((prevState) => [...prevState, ...res.data.users]);
        setHasMore(users.length >= res.data.total);
        setLoading(false);
        console.log(res.data);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        if (axios.isCancel(e)) return;
        console.log(e);
        setError(true);
      });
    return () => cancel();
  }, [query, pageNumber, users]);
  return { loading, error, users, hasMore };
}
```

Comment: It is like, whenever the component is unmounted for some reason, say user clicked back button on browser, or navigated to a different route (during the API call) IT cancels(aborts) the on-going request which is not required obviously .... so is the `cancel()` does all this in the return callback of `useEffect` ... hope it gave some idea :)

Answer (score 1):

The cancel token is used to cancel a request, but it is using deprecated API. Axios has newer API for that too.

As far as `useEffect` is concerned, the cancellation happens in the function which is returned by `useEffect`, that function runs when component *unmounts* and *when any of its dependencies change*.

Idea is for example if I have an ongoing query for keyword "Nick" and suddenly query was changed to "John", we are not interested in "Nick" query anymore so we can cancel it. Also if we don't cancel it and execute both queries "Nick" may arrive later, and overwrite result for "John".

Comment: Thanks for the example, the example I gave is also valid isn't it ?

Comment: @KcH Yeah almost, you just mentioned that it gets called only on unmount.